# Protractor scroll into view not working

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am new to using protractor and want to visually see my web page scroll down to an element and it is not working. I understand scroll into allows me to visually see the scroll happen window.scroll to my understanding dosent all that. Any help would be appreciated

HTML CODE

a class="button button--secondary promo--app-button" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/homes.com-real-estate-search/id306423353?mt=8&uo=4" target="_blank" data-tl-object="app_referral_hdc_portalhomefeatured_ios">
                        Apple Store

Protractor code:

```
it('scroll down page for (dropdown header search)', function () { 
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        var scrolldown = $$('.button button--secondary promo--app-button').get(1);

        scrolldown.scrollIntoView(true);

        browser.sleep(10000);
    })
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using browser.executeScript:

```
    var scrolldown = $$('.button button--secondary promo--app-button').get(1);
    browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
        browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', scrolldown.getWebElement());
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: can just clicking be enough for protractor to scroll into view ?

Answer (score 3):

This should be simple.
Just get the web-element's cor-ordinates and use Window.scroll

```
    var elm = element(by.xpath("//blahblah"));
    elm.getLocation()
        .then(function(location) {
            return browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(' + location.x + ', ' + location.y + ');');
        })
```